# dynamic Add,Edit,Delete collection of model binding in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-binding

I want Dynamic Add,Edit,Delete Collection of ModelBinding in mvc asp.net.I have following code sample.There is a problem when I dynamic add Quantity through jquery the server validation did not work.My requirement is I want to add,edit Quantity and delete quantity with validaions and In case of  edit the quantity,if user want to delete quantity,the quantity will not delete unless user press edit records(Save records).Following is sample code.I want to handle Add,Edit in one view

```
public class CreateRecipeModel
{
   Public int    Id // This is  primary key
required
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<IngredientModel> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientModel
{

    Public int    Id   // This is  primary key
required
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
  Public int    NId { get; set; }// This is  foriegn key of Parent table
}


View
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => model => model.Name)
<input type=”button” value=”Add” class=”AddQuantity”/>

for (var i = 0 ; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ingredients[i].Id)
       @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ingredients[i].Quantity)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ingredients [i].Quantity)
        <input type=”button” value=”delete” class=”deleteQuantity”/>
    }

<input type=”button” value=”SaveReocrds”>
```

[ADD View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COMGK.png)

[Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/512C6.png)